# Is there any way to know that particular element is present in someother html page

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing processing with html page elements like button or text box.
I can not change the code or can not write any code on that particular page.
Therefore before i am doing that i want to check that all element are present in that page.
For Example- I have HTML page.
So is there any way to validate that all the element are presented in other html page by javascript or another way.

any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this using jQuery:

```
var $button = $("button");
if($button.length !== 0) {
    // button exists do something
} else {
    // button DOES NOT exist do something else
}
```

try in javascript:

```
var $button = document.getelememtById("button"); /* button had an ID of #button */
if($button.length !== 0) {
    // button exists do something
} else {
    // button DOES NOT exist do something else
}
```

basically you check the length of that DOM object and do something if its length is not zero

of course this just gives you a proof of concept to use on those elements you want to test against

Comment: @jonathan-  within same page i understand, i can do but for which web page elements i would like validate, i cant change the code of that page. this is any many problem, is there an way to validate without doing any modification on that web page.

Comment: what version of jQuery are you using? ..is the HTML on the other page on the same server? .. and you could use AJAX to fetch fragments of the page and parse that HTML to see if those elements exist .. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: @jonathan- did not know about jQuery version because it is a client web application and hosted in client environment. No other page will be in local system from where i am doing testing or validating elements. Now possible jonathan or not

Comment: is it possible for you to inspect the code in the browser to see if it uses jQuery or does it use native javascript?

Comment: did not on this point of time. let say they are using native javascript. i am only concern about that button or text box is present or not. that only.

Comment: you dont have an example to go by to better help you

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can write something that would compare the DOM of the two html pages.

Comment: which web page elements i would like validate, i cant change the code of that page. this is any many problem, is there an way to validate without doing any modification on that web page